# Singletons in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to keep my player when switching scenes but without getting lots of copies of it , so I found out about singletons.You do something like this:

```
public class Player : Monobehaviour
{
   private static Player instance = null;
   void Start()
       {
        if (instance == null)
          {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameobject); 
          }
        else 
         Destroy(gameobject);
          
       }
}
```

And it's pretty hard for me to understand.I get how static variables work , they belong to the class not to the instance.So , first my objects is in scene A.I switch to scene B,a new gameobject will be created with the script Player on it.Now , since instance holds the reference to the gameobject in scene A , why won't the else statement get called and a new gameobject will actually be created?Also , if you could explain a little bit more detailed than unitydoc how DontDestroyOnLoad() works , I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

This code runs *after* the object is created. In fact it runs on a script on the GameObject.  The *else* statement *will* run, and it will destroy the GameObject this script is attached to, which is what you want because you already had another copy in the world from previously (the one that is referenced by the "instance" variable).

Answer (score 0):

JSchiff is correct that this code will run after an instance of this object is created, storing the current instance in your static variable for unconditional access to "the current instance" or destroying new instances if there is one already. The `else` branch in your code will run.

To answer your extended question about `DontDestroyOnLoad` and it's interaction with this static variable: all the objects in the `Engine` are held in `memory` by the `Engine`. A `Scene` can be thought of as a "collection of objects in memory" by the engine. When a scene is unloaded, all objects in that collection are destroyed, unless the engine has been told `DontDestroyOnLoad` (as in un-load, although documentation refers to it as a "swap". You can load scenes without unloading scenes, this might have been terminology which just grew outdated but that's conjecture on my part).

These ideas are combined to make your Singleton, a highly accessible (in this case `static` instance variable), persistent (through `DontDestroyOnLoad`), one of a kind (through destroying any instance after the first) object. This isn't the only way to apply the Singleton pattern, but it is a common one in Unity.